# How to find performance bottleneck in application?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, iis

Question is a bit general, but I'll try my best to ask it correctly.

So I started supporting system which is composed of parts:

- Client Application (.net/c#)
- WebService Server (IIS 6)
- DB (Oracle 10g)

In client application, user is making reports requests, which are proceeded by the web service, and the data is taken from DB.
And some of these reports are proceeding VERY SLOW. About 1 hour for proceeding about 100 000 rows from 1 table.

So I want to know, which part of the system is slowing the whole system down. 
What are the most common practics to find this out? I understand that the question is very complex and general and recommending particular instrument is quite impossible. But what are common tactics? What is usual way to find out if system is slowing down on DB, web service or client side?

Comment: you'll need profilers. basic profilers can be found built-in Visual Studio 2015, while other 3rd party vendors build pretty advanced products to profile both desktop and web applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use profilers.You can find "Hot spots" based on profiling methods(eg CPU Sampling ,Instrumentation...and etc) .Personally for C# client i use visual studio profiler ,Jabraines DotTrace  and ANT Memory profiler .Additionally you can use windows performance monitor as well. I use SQL profiler and RedGate Profiler for Database profiling.But there are more profilers available over the internet.Just have a research on Google and select a suitable one.

Comment: Thanks @Thabo! I Think this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You may have answered your own question in the "where", ie have a look at the queries called when running the reports. As for the "How" have a look at the tools/profilers available to profile your application and the database.